# Can't capture google map with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a problem when capture screen with html2canvas  of html2canvas.hertzen.com, when I capture Map of google map in my page I can't see map

My map

[image]

My capture

[image]

My code

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
```

Anyone got a tip? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me for Chrome and Firefox:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
      proxy: "server.js",
      useCORS: true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
    });
```

where server.js is https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs
There are other proxies available for PHP and Python that I haven't tried yet. I cannot post both but if you google "html2canvas proxy" you'll be able to find the others if you need them.

Comment: I use html2canvas (from html2canvas.hertzen.com) to capture screenshot. I got this strange error like this: The code of my webpage is put on one host, say Host A. If my webpage contains an image on another host, say Host B, then I hit this error: Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

However, the confusing part is that if Host B is facebook (my image is a direct link to facebook https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/372701_100000684388457_1551561655_q.jpg) then the error disappear.

Comment: My function

html2canvas([document.body], {
                    useCORS : true,
                    logging : true,
                    onrendered : function(canvas) {
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        window.open(myImage);
                    }
Anyone got a tip? Tks

Comment: Check out this issue on the html2canvas github issue page, it should help you out: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/248

Answer (score 0):

```
  html2canvas(document.body, {
      proxy: "/my-proxy",
    }).then((canvas) => {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
```

**IMPORTANT**: Don't add **useCORS: true** if you using **proxy: "/my-proxy"** setting.

The plugin will send the request in the next format

```
https://your-site.com/my-proxy?url=https://path-to-image.jpg&responseType=blob
```

More information about the proxy server is available [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/proxy).